# cudaMemcpy always returns me cudaErrorInvalidValue

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I have an issue against cudaMalloc function use. Indeed, it always returns me a "cudaErrorInvalidValue" error even in a very simple case like this example below :

```
cudaError_t error;
int hostTest = 12;
int* deviceTest = NULL;
error = cudaMemcpy(deviceTest, &hostTest, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

However, cudaMalloc works well. It's quite strange. 
My build is configured for compute capabilities v5.0 (compute_50,sm_50) and my graphics card is a Geforce GTX 960M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example you need to allocate memory with `cudaMalloc`and assign the pointer it returns to `deviceTest` since this variable is meant point to memory in the device.

Something like this should do the trick

```
 int hostTest = 12;
 int *deviceTest;
 cudaMalloc((void **)&deviceTest,sizeof(int));
 cudaMemcpy(deviceTest, &hostTest,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```